# How can I make this logic run through 3 types of agents?

Tags: anylogic

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEPkd.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p3Ua.png)

As pic1 shows, in my logic, I've got 2 types of agents, so I set 3 sources. However, when I run the model, It couldn't through the queue and next steps, I think it's because of the setting of agent type. Do you know how can I set that agent type that can make 3 different agents go through this logic?

Comment: Please advise exactly what error you get during model execution

Answer (score 0):

if a block in your process is handling several types of agents, it can definitely do it without issues, you don't need to touch the advanced settings, but if you did, change the agent type to Agent.

This Agent selection in the agent type is done automatically in AnyLogic, and that's why you should never touch the advanced section if you don't know what you are doing.

If it still doesn't work, it means that your error is different and not due to the different agent types, in which case you will need to specify the error you are experiencing